# Django: When extending User, better to use OneToOneField(User) or ForeignKey(User, unique=True)?

Tags: django, django-models, django-users, django-profiles

I'm finding conflicting information on whether to use `OneToOneField(User)` or `ForeignKey(User, unique=True)` when creating a `UserProfile` model by extending the Django User model.

Is it better to use this?:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

or this?:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

The [Django Doc](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) specifies `OneToOneField`, while the [Django Book example](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter12/#cn222) uses `ForeignKey`.

[James Bennett](http://www.b-list.org/) also has two Blog posts that providing conflicting examples as well:

- [Extending the User Model](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jun/06/django-tips-extending-user-model/)
- [User Registration](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/sep/02/django-tips-user-registration/)

In the former post, Bennett provides some reasons why he switched to using `ForeignKey` instead of `OneToOneField`, but I don't quite get it, especially when I see other posts that recommend the opposite.

I'm curious to know your preference and why. Or, does it even matter?

Comment: I see nothing in Bennett's first article regarding user profiles.

Comment: @Ignacio - Sorry, I added a link to the wrong article. It should have been to his post on "Extending the User Model". I've corrected the link. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: For me, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870537/whats-the-difference-between-django-onetoonefield-and-foreignkey is more clear to understand

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The only real reason given in the article is that it can be set up so that the admin page for `User` will show both the fields in `User` and `UserProfile`. This can be replicated with a `OneToOneField` with a little elbow grease, so unless you're addicted to showing it in the admin page with no work at the cost of a bit of clarity ("We can create multiple profiles per user?! Oh no, wait, it's set unique.") I'd use `OneToOneField`.

Answer (score 7):

Besides the admin page inlines, other reason for the `ForeignKey` solution is that it allows you to use the correct, default DB manager when objects are accessed with a reverse relation. Consider example from this [subclasses manager snippet](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1037/). Let's say that the `Post` class definition from the example looks like this:

```
class Post(ParentModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    onetoone = models.ForeignKey(SomeModel, unique=True)

    children = ChildManager()
    objects = models.Manager()
```

By calling `somemodel_instance.post_set.all()[0]`, you get the desired subclasses objects of the `Post` class as indicated by defining the first (default) manager as a `ChildManager`. On the other hand, with `OneToOneField`, by calling `somemodel_instance.post` you get the `Post` class instance. You can always call `somemodel_instance.post.subclass_object` and get the same result, but the default manager could do any other sort of tricks and the `FK` solutions hides them nicely.

If you own and can modify the custom manager code you can use the [`use_for_related_fields`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#manager-types) attribute instead of using FK in place of legitimate 1to1 field, but even that can fail because of some not-known to me nuisances of the automatic managers. As far as I remember it will fail in the above example.

Answer (score 5):

Other reason to generally not use the `OneToOneField` related to reverse relations: when you use reverse relations defined via `OneToOneField` you get an model instance, contrary to `Manager` for `ForeignKey` reverse relation and as a consequence there's always a DB hit. This is costly if you do some generic stuff on reverse relations (via `_meta.get_all_related_objects()`) and do not know and care if you will use them all or not.