# Get rid of get_profile() in a migration to Django 1.6

Tags: python, django, deprecated, user-profile

With Django 1.5 and the introduction of custom user models the `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` became deprecated. In my existing Django application I use the `User` model and I also have a `Profile` model with a foreign key to the `User` and store other stuff about the user in the profile. Currently using `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` and this is set to 'app.profile'.
So obviously, my code tends to do lots of `user.get_profile()` and this now needs to go away.

Now, I could create a new custom user model (by just having my profile model extend `User`) but then in all other places where I currently have a foreign key to a user will need to be changed also... so this would be a large migration in my live service.

Is there any way - and with no model migration - and only by creating/overriding the `get_profile()` function with something like `my_user.userprofile_set.all()[0]`) somewhere?

Anyone out there that has gone down this path and can share ideas or experiences?

If I where to do this service again now - would obviously not go this way but with a semi-large live production system I am open for short-cuts :-)

Comment: These are the steps I have ended up doing;

(i) created a utils method that does: return user.profile_set.all()[0] (ii) added in all places where I reference User with a foreignkey in my models - also added a property user_profile(self) that returns the above utils method on self (iii) last added current user profile and made it available under the request context (allowing me to replace all usages in templates of user.get_profile with user_profile (that I had added). Then lots of search and replace of .get_profile in code - but seems to work now. Not the most pretty thing but works.

Comment: I want to follow this approach but I don't quite understand it. Where are you adding the property `user_profile`? How are you making it available in the request context?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Using a profile model with a relation to the built-in `User` is still a totally legitimate construct for storing additional user information (and recommended in many cases). The `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` and `get_profile()` stuff that is now deprecated just ended up being unnecessary, given that built-in Django 1-to-1 syntax works cleanly and elegantly here.

The transition from the old usage is actually easy if you're already **using a `OneToOneField` to `User` on your profile model**, which is how [the profile module was recommended to be set up before get_profile was deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users).

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")
    # add profile fields here, e.g.,
    nickname = CharField(...)

# usage: no get_profile() needed. Just standard 1-to-1 reverse syntax!
nickname = request.user.profile.nickname
```

See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) if you're not familiar with the syntactic magic for `OneToOneField`'s that makes this possible.  It ends up being a simple search and replace of `get_profile()` for `profile` or whatever your `related_name` is (auto related name in the above case would be `user_profile`). Standard django reverse 1-1 syntax is actually nicer than `get_profile()`!

### Change a ForeignKey to a OneToOneField

However, I realize this doesn't answer your question entirely. You indicate that you used a `ForeignKey` to `User` in your profile module rather than a `OneToOne`, which is fine, but the syntax isn't as simple if you leave it as a `ForeignKey`, as you note in your follow up comment.
Assuming you were using your `ForeignKey` in practice as an unique foreign key (essentially a 1-to-1), given that [in the DB a `OneToOneField` is just a `ForeignKey` field with a `unique=True` constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870537/whats-the-difference-between-django-onetoonefield-and-foreignkey), you should be able to **change the `ForeignKey` field to a `OneToOneField`** in your code without actually having to make a significant database migration or incurring any data loss.

### Dealing with South migration

If you're using *[South](http://south.aeracode.org/)* for migrations, the code change from the previous section may confuse South into deleting the old field and creating a new one if you do a `schemamigration --auto`, so you may need to manually edit the migration to do things right. One approach would be to create the schemamigration and then blank out the forwards and backwards methods so it doesn't actually try to do anything, but so it still freezes the model properly as a `OneToOneField` going forward. Then, if you want to do things perfectly, you should add the unique constraint to the corresponding database foreign key column as well. You can either do this manually with SQL, or via South (by either editing the migration methods manually, or by setting `unique=True` on the `ForeignKey` and creating a first South migration before you switch it to a `OneToOneField` and do a second migration and blank out the forwards/backwards methods).

Comment: Very neat answer. You'll win the bounty tomorrow, in 23 hours :)