# Django. get_profile() don't work

Tags: python, django

I want to get information from current user in my forms.py

My Model:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField('First name', max_length=50)
        ....
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, editable=False)
```

My view:

```
@login_required
def editAccount(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditAccountForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

My Form:

```
class EditAccountForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Users

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):

        self.user = user.get_profile()
```

I put in my settings.py  AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = "user.Users", I have this error: Deprecation Warning: The use of AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE to define user profiles has been deprecated. self.user = user.get_profile()
I'm new on django I don't see my mistake.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no error in your code. What you see is just a deprecation warning.

Starting Django 1.5, [AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE has been deprecated](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releases/1.5.html#auth-profile-module) in favour of custom User models.

Your code should still work though, but ideally you should read up on [custom User model](http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/auth/customizing.html#auth-custom-user) and start using it.

Answer (score 2):

The AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE setting, and the django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_profile() was depreciated in Django 1.5 See [AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#auth-profile-module)

For your code try this:

models.y

```
class Users(models.Model):
    user = OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")
```

forms.py

```
class EditAccountForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Users

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user.profile
```

[Here's the related question with answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613315/get-rid-of-get-profile-in-a-migration-to-django-1-6)

Answer (score -1):

Another thing that you could do is simple call the model that created the user and
request for the information. IE

## Your created user profile.

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, editable=False)
    first_name = models.CharField("Last name", max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.username
```

## Then in your view you could do something like

```
class UserProfileView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        self.user = request.user

        #from here you can call your user model requesting for the user information.
        self.userdetails = Users.objects.get(username=self.user)
        if(self.userdetails):
            #user exists
            #you can pass this to the templates and perform actions on using loops
            for details in self.userdetails:
                print details.username
                print details.first_name
                print details.last_name
                #.....
```