# One-To-One relationship, put foreign key in master table or slave table?

Tags: python, django, relationship

I have two table(One-To-One relationship) :

```
class Member(models.Model):
    openid = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    realname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    join_date = models.DateField()
    ....more data ...


class MemberProfile(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    ....more data ...
```

Apparently, `Member` is master table and `MemberProfile` is slave.
But I find it is inconvenient to get `MemberProfile`'s data through by `Member`.
If `Member` has a  ForeignKey link to `MemberProfile`,such as :

```
class Member(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(MemberProfile)
    openid = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    realname = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    join_date = models.DateField()
    ....more data ...
```

I can get the profile from a member more easily.
`member = Member.objects.get(id=id)`
I can retrieve profile by `member.profile` rather than one more sentence:`profile = MemberProfile.objects.get(member=member)`

Is it better to move ForeignKey define in `Member` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [OnetoOneField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#ref-onetoone) for the member:

```
class MemberProfile:
    member = models.OneToOneField(Member)
```

Then you can access a member's profile like this:

```
member.memberprofile
```

Relevant quote from the docs:

> Conceptually, this is similar to a ForeignKey with unique=True, but the “reverse” side of the relation will directly return a single object.

Comment: No, you are wrong.How can you use `member.profile` as you do not define `profile` in `Member`? See [What's the difference between django OneToOneField and ForeignKey?][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870537/whats-the-difference-between-django-onetoonefield-and-foreignkey]

Comment: @Mithril yes, that is what django let's you do. It does a 'reverse' lookup and the example you linked to does exactly this. Even though Engine doesn't define a Car field, you can access e.car which is the Car object that has the foreign key to e

Comment: I see,it is `memberprofile` , not `profile`.django will auto lowercase the OneToOneField model name.Can I change `memberprofile` to another name? I mean, can I define a name in `Member` as a holder,it would be much more clear for others to understand this model.

Comment: @Mithril you can use `related_name` in the field definition to change the reverse accessor.

Answer (score 0):

As per your models.

```
class Member(models.Model):
    openid = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    ....more data ...


class MemberProfile(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position)
    ....more data ...
```

It is not much inconvenient to get `MemberProfile` data if we are having `Member` object

```
member_object = Member.objects.get(id=1)
print member_object.memberprofile_set.all()     # here you can access MemberProfile 
                                                #data by using reverse relationship
```

you can customize result as per your need like below :

```
print member_object.memberprofile_set.filter(mobile='9717353657')
print member_object.memberprofile_set.filter(mobile='9717353657').values_list('email')
```

also it is better to making `Member` model as master table.