# Difference between django's OneToOneField and django's OneToOneRel

Tags: django

What's the main difference between django's OneToOneField and django's OneToOneRel.

When I searched I came across:

[What's the difference between django OneToOneField and ForeignKey?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870537/whats-the-difference-between-django-onetoonefield-and-foreignkey)

Answer (score 19):

OneToOneRel is an internal class which implements the back reference of a one to one relationship. It is not documented anywhere, not part of any public api, and is not for use in your app.

Answer (score 8):

First I thought, there is no 'OneToOneRel'. But there is. It's not in the documentation. But it lives in the Django source code. So there is the first difference. ;)

I decided to look up the OneToOneField in the Django source. This is the [docstring for the OneToOneField](https://github.com/django/django/blob/84b6c768301096849f5589d7612b129c5445abd3/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L2025):

> A OneToOneField is essentially the same as a ForeignKey, with the
>   exception that always carries a "unique" constraint with it and the
>   reverse relation always returns the object pointed to (since there
>   will only ever be one), rather than returning a list.

But we allready knew that. Cool thing is, a [few lines down](https://github.com/django/django/blob/84b6c768301096849f5589d7612b129c5445abd3/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L2037) you see:

```
rel_class = OneToOneRel
```

So the second difference is that OneToOneRel is used in OneToOneField.

Than I searched for OneToOneRel in this Python file and found:

```
class OneToOneRel(ManyToOneRel):
    ...
```

So the third difference is that OneToOneRel is a subclass of ManyToOneRel but OneToOneField is a subclass of ForeignKey.

For me this is enough to know: OneToOneRel is used in a OneToOneField. OneToOneRel is what a ManyToOneRel is for a ForeignKey and a ManyToManyRel for a ManyToManyField. Those rel classes seem to handle constraints.

The important part: You can't compare OneToOneField with OneToOneRel in the same way you can compare OneToOneField with ForeignKey because OneToOneRel is not a relationship field.