# Setting unique=True on a ForeignKey has the same effect as using a OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-1.8

I switched to Django 1.8.2 from 1.7 recently, but I encounter with a little bit issues, for example in one of my models I have:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, blank=False, primary_key=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

But when I run server I come across with this following warning:

```
WARNINGS:
exam.Author.author: (fields.W342) Setting unique=True on a ForeignKey has the same effect as using a OneToOneField.
HINT: ForeignKey(unique=True) is usually better served by a OneToOneField.
```

What should I do?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The warning is giving you information.

Comment: warning != error. The OneToOne field already ensures the uniqueness.

Comment: I haven't unique option or OneToOneField!  What is the warning denoting?

Comment: Have a look at the source of the OneToOneField: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L2077

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`primary_key` implies `unique=True`. So, as the warning says, you should probably be using a OneToOneField.

Answer (score 3):

As [Daniel said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30915554/1071884) you are probably better off using a `OneToOneField`.

A good explanation as to why this is can be found at [this Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5870537/1071884).

Answer (score 0):

In Short, Django is asking you is to replace your ForeignKey field with this:

```
author = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, blank=False, primary_key=True)
```

Also, I shall suggest to add an **on_delete** key, and make it something like:

```
author = models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, blank=False, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Reference:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/