# ForeignKey is null after POST in Django Rest (Nested Serializer)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I am a newbie in Django, and I had implemented a one-to-many relationship, however one fieled which is nested is null.

When I post `destinations` is null in the response section. Below is my response section :

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Germany tour",
    "description": "This is a fascinating tour to take",
    "price": "30.0",
    "destinations": null,
    "capacity": 10
}
```

This is the way I am posting in the **Body** section in postman :

```
{
    "name": "Germany tour",
    "description": "This is a fascinating tour to take",
    "price": 30.0,
    "destinations": [
        {
            "location":"Germany",
            "tour_type":"Adventure",
            "danger_type":"Medium"
        }
],
    "capacity": 10
}
```

Then, below is my **models** file  :

```
from django.db import models


class Destinations(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    tour_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    danger_type = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['location', 'tour_type']


class TourPackages(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=1)
    destinations = models.ForeignKey(Destinations, related_name="destinations", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    capacity = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Then, my **serializers** file :

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import TourPackages, Destinations


class DestinationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Destinations
        fields = ['tour_type', 'danger_type']


class TourPackagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    destinations = DestinationSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TourPackages
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'destinations', 'capacity']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        destination_data = validated_data.pop("destinations")
        location = TourPackages.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for dest_data in destination_data:
            Destinations.objects.create(location=location, **dest_data)

        return location
```

Then finally my **views** file :

```
from rest_framework import generics

from .models import TourPackages
from .serializer import TourPackagesSerializer


class TourList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = TourPackages.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TourPackagesSerializer


class TourDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = TourPackages.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TourPackagesSerializer
```

What I want is to post all the data and comes back in response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create `Destinations` object first in order to assign them in case of `ForeignKey`. From the sample data you have posted it implies that you can have multiple `destinations` and you have `on_delete=models.CASCADE` set on that. Suppose for a particular tour you have`4` destinations and you decide to delete two of them, then `models.CASCADE` will try to delete your `tours` object. If this happens where will the remaining `2` destinations object point to? `Database integrity` will be lost. So `Django` will not allow this. You can fix by changing `ForeignKey` To `ManyToManyField`.
And your `TourPackagesSerializer` should be like this:

Building on the answer from Ananya:

```
class TourPackagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    destinations = DestinationSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TourPackages
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'description', 'price', 'destinations', 'capacity']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        destination_data = validated_data.pop('destinations')
        dest_obj_list = []
        for dest_data in destination_data:
            dest_obj = Destinations.objects.create(**dest_data)
            dest_obj_list.append(dest_obj)
        location = TourPackages.objects.create(**validated_data)
        location.destinations.set(dest_obj_list)
        location.save()
        return location
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you saved my life.

Comment: Though I think am still struggling to differentiate or when to use Many-t0-many and )ne-to-many. Any insight will be welcomed

Comment: You can have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870537/whats-the-difference-between-django-onetoonefield-and-foreignkey)

Answer (score 0):

In the create method you are creating the destination objects but not setting the Foreign Key in location. Try this:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    destination_data = validated_data.pop('destinations')
    dest_obj_list = []
    for dest_data in destination_data:
        dest_obj = Destinations.objects.create(location=location, **dest_data)
        dest_obj_list.append(dest_obj)
    location = TourPackages.objects.create(**validated_data)
    location.destinations.set(dest_obj_list)
    location.save()
```

Comment: `set` method will not work on `ForeignKey`, [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/). Plus `Destinations.objects.create(location=location, **dest_data)` will also give error, since `location` object has been not created yet.