# How can I delete the answers (code in body)?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I am creating a Q&A website for practice, I created the answer and the question model and linked them together, however I can not access the template that I set for the deletion of the answer model, I created a `DeleteView` to delete the question. Here is the code:

**views.py**:

```
class Politics_post_details(DeleteView):
    model = PoliticsPost
    context_object_name = 'politicsposts'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'qid'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # now you can get any additional information you want from other models
        question = get_object_or_404(PoliticsPost, pk=self.kwargs.get('qid'))
        context['answers'] = Answer.objects.filter(post=question).order_by('-date_posted')
        return context

class AnswerDelete(UserPassesTestMixin,DetailView):
    model = Answer
    success_url = reverse_lazy('Lisk home')
    pk_url_kwarg = 'aid'

    def test_func(self):
        answer = self.get_object()
        if self.request.user ==answer.author:
            return True
        return False
```

**urls.py**(not root):

```
path('politicspost/<int:qid>/createanswer/',views.CreateAnswer.as_view(template_name='lisk_templates/createanswer.html'),name = 'Answer'),
path('politicspost/<int:qid>/answer/<int:aid>/delete/',views.AnswerDelete.as_view(template_name = 'lisk_templates/answer_delete.html'),name='Answer_Delete'), 
path('politicspost/<int:qid>/',views.Politics_post_details.as_view(template_name='lisk_templates/politics_post_details.html'),
```

I created the template but whenever I try to access it, it gives me an error as follows:

```
NoReverseMatch at /politicspost/29/
Reverse for 'Answer_Delete' with arguments '(36,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['politicspost/(?P<qid>[0-9]+)/answer/(?P<aid>[0-9]+)/delete/$']
```

Thanks in advance.

answer_delete.html:

```
{%extends "lisk_templates/base.html"%}
{% block title %}
    Page title
{% endblock title %}

{% block body%}

<div class="feed" style="background-color:lightred;"><form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h3>Are you sure that you want to delete this answer: <br>
        {{ object.content }}</h3>
    <button id="signin" type="submit">Yes</button>  <a href="{% url 'politics_post_details' object.id %}" style="margin-left:10px;"> No</a>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues. The biggest one is that you have switched `DeleteView` and `DetailView` (your `DeleteView` is a `DetailView` and vice versa).

And then you should either rename your template to `answer_confirm_delete` or add the `template_name_suffix` to your `DeleteView`. See the documentation for further details:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView

If you use Django's DeleteView, you don't need to specify a url in the template, it will do all the work for you. Just make sure you specify the url correctly in your `urls.py`. Fix these issues and see if it works then.

Comment: In the template just created the url that will redirect the user if he/she decided not to delete the answer. I added I already added the template name suffix but in the urls.py, I corrected the delete view and it was not the issue. @MeL

Answer (score 1):

#### May Be This Might Work For You, Because You Never Used The Import Of DeleteView

```
from django.views.generic import DeleteView

"""This Is From My Blog App, That I Used For My Blog App, Hope This Will Help"""
class PostDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('post_list')
```

**Happy Coding, *let me know if there are any issues with this* I'am Up for you!**

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but although this stupid mistake would have resulted in many issues, it was not the cause of this specific problem, I still get the same error, thanks for pointing this out again, I feel so stupid. @Aryan Mishra