# Two or more unique Foreign keys from same model (dependent chain)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So i have a model like this

```
class ExaminationCenter(models.Model):
    district = models.ForeignKey(District, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And another model like this

```
class ExamForm(models.Model):
    exam_centre_1 = models.ForeignKey(ExaminationCenter, on_delete=models.cascade)
    exam_centre_2 = models.ForeignKey(ExaminationCenter, on_delete=models.cascade)
    exam_centre_3 = models.ForeignKey(ExaminationCenter, on_delete=models.cascade)
```

Is there any way to make these three fields to hold the unique item from the same foreign key model.

For example if user choose a **exam center** in *exam_center_1* then that examination center should not be available for *exam_center_2* and *exam_center_3*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go look up the onetoonefield and onetomanyfield in django doc.
or look through this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870537/whats-the-difference-between-django-onetoonefield-and-foreignkey)