# django why getting this error 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'email_confirmed'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

When I am using `user.email_confirmed` I am not getting any error but when using `user.userprofile.email_confirmed` getting RelatedManager error. Why I am getting this error when trying to get user details from userprofile model?

here is my code:

```
class UserManagement(AbstractUser):
          is_blog_author = models.BooleanField(default=False)
          is_editor = models.BooleanField(default=False)
          is_subscriber = models.BooleanField(default=False)
          is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
          email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False) #there is no error when obtaining email_confirmed object from abstract user model.  

class UserProfile(models.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="userprofile")
      email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)


#I am using this for email verification 
class AccountActivationTokenGenerator(PasswordResetTokenGenerator):
    def _make_hash_value(self, user, timestamp):
        return (
            six.text_type(user.pk) + six.text_type(timestamp) +
            six.text_type(user.userprofile.email_confirmed) #error rising for this line 
            #six.text_type(user.email_confirmed) #I am not getting error if I use this line 
        )

account_activation_token = AccountActivationTokenGenerator()
```

**views.py**

```
....others code 
if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
            user.userprofile.email_confirmed = True #why it's not working and rising error? 
            #user.email_confirmed = True #it's working 
            user.save()
            .....others code
```

Comment: UserProfile uses a ForeignKey, rather than a OneToOneField, so it is possible for each user to have multiple UserProfile objects. You therefore need to filter the `user.userprofile` queryset down to a single object before you can use it. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870537/whats-the-difference-between-django-onetoonefield-and-foreignkey

Comment: @Nick ODell should I use user.userprofile.filter(email_confirmed = True) for six??? can you please show me which query set will be appropriate for  `user.userprofile.email_confirmed` and `user.userprofile.email_confirmed = True`

Answer (score 0):

as @Nick ODell told me I need to be use filter.

The problem was occurring for this two queryset:
`user.userprofile.email_confirmed` and `user.userprofile.email_confirmed = True` after I changed theme

`user.userprofile.filter(email_confirmed=False)` and  `user.userprofile.filter(email_confirmed=False).update(email_confirmed=True)` my problem solved.