# Cannot the parent model's object use `_set` with `OneToOneField()` in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, one-to-one

I have `Person` model and `PersonDetail` model with [OneToOneField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) as shown below:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class PersonDetail(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

But, when using `persondetail_set` of a `Person` object as shown below:

```py
obj = Person.objects.get(id=1)
print(obj.persondetail_set.get(id=1))
        # ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑
```

Then, there is the error below:

> AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'persondetail_set'

So, I used [ForeignKey()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) as shown below:

```py
class PersonDetail(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # ...
```

Then, there was no error:

```
PersonDetail object (1)
```

Or, I used [ManyToManyField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield) as shown below:

```py
class PersonDetail(models.Model):
    person = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
    # ...
```

Then, there was no error:

```
PersonDetail object (1)
```

So, cannot the parent model's object use `_set` with `OneToOneField()` in Django?

```py
obj = Person.objects.get(id=1)
print(obj.persondetail_set.get(id=1))
        # ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑
```

Comment: No, because in a 1-to-1 relation, having `_set` as the name of the relation doesn't make sense(because we know there will be almost one related object). Hence, Django allows us to access it directly, but since you don't have `related_name` defined it uses a lowercase version of your model: `person_obj.persondetail`.

Answer (score 1):

> So, doesn't the parent model's object of one-to-one relationship have
> _set in Django?

Why would have it, when `OneToOne` has got max 1 related object? `_set` is created only for relation that can be with many objects, like `ManyToMany` or `OneToMany` (`ForeignKey`).

By default (if you have no `related_name` set) for `OneToOne` instead of `persondetail_set.all()` use just `persondetail`.