# get_profile alternative in for loop django

Tags: django

I'm trying to get information of a users avatar based in an extended profile model. I usually call the information via get_profile(). However on this occasion the call is within a for loop in the template and I get errors if one of the users are the same.

How would I go about avoiding this error?

```
{% for fevent in fevents %}      
                   <!-- EVENT ><!   -->
              <div class="event">
                        <div class="pic">
                            <a href="" class="notification" title="{{ fevent.getPublishedPredictionsCount }} Predictions">{{ fevent.getPublishedPredictionsCount }}</a>
                            <img src="{% thumbnail fevent.artwork.get_absolute_url 100x98 crop,upscale %}" alt="" width="100" height="98" />
                            <div class="overlay">
                                <a href=""></a>
                             </div>
                         </div>

                         <h1><a href="">{{ fevent.title|trunchar:30 }}</a></h1>

                           {% autoescape off %}
                            {{ fevent.getEventPredictionScore|makestars }}
                           {% endautoescape %}

                        <ul class="details">
                            <li class="cat">
                                Category: <a href="">{{ fevent.catagory }}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="location">
                                {{ fevent.location }}
                            </li>
                            <li class="date">
                                {{ fevent.date_and_time }}
                            </li>
                            <li class="time">
                                7:00pm - 8:00pm
                            </li>


                        </ul>
                        <!-- CLEAR ><!   --><div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="hype">
                            <div class="avatar">
                                <a href="" class="overlay" title="{{ fevent.owner.get_full_name }}"></a><img src="{% thumbnail fevent.owner.get_profile.avatar.get_absolute_url 120x120 crop,upscale %}" alt="" width="120" height="120" />
                            </div>
                            <p>{{ fevent.description|trunchar:200 }}… <a href="">Read More</a></p>
                        </div>

                         <!-- CLEAR ><!   --><div class="clear"></div>

              </div>

                   <!-- END OF EVENT ><!   -->
{% endfor %}
```

The problem is here:

```
{% thumbnail fevent.owner.get_profile.avatar.get_absolute_url 120x120 crop,upscale %}
```

Error Message returned:

```
Caught MultipleObjectsReturned while rendering: get() returned more than one UserProfile -- it returned 2! Lookup parameters were {'user__id__exact': 4L}
```

Comment: Please add the error message.

Comment: This is the downside of [having a FK to `User` in your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221745/django-when-extending-user-better-to-use-onetoonefielduser-or-foreignkeyuser).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means there are two `UserProfile` objects in the database matching the query used by `get_profile`, not that `get_profile` was called twice. You need to remove one of those profile objects from the database and make sure there aren't multiples created again. You should be able to use the `get_profile` method multiple times without issue. Maybe you have a `get_or_create` call in that function without checking the proper values.

Comment: It wasn't get_or_create that cause the issue. I had to change a few things in another model which deleted the linked models information userprofile being included in one of them. It didn't remove the items from the mysql database however, which is where the duplicate items came from I believe.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on what Matt said, while using `get_or_create` is a good idea, you should definitely define your profile model's `User` link with a `OneToOneField`, instead of a `ForeignKey`.

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name=_(u'user'))
```

Now, if you forget to use `get_or_create()`, or somehow accidentally try to create a duplicate profile for the same user, the database will raise an `IntegrityError`.