# Under the hoods what's the difference between subclassing the user and creating a one to one field?

Tags: python, django

I want to implement users in my system. I know that Django already has an authentication system, and I've been reading the documentation. But I don't know yet the difference between

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
class Profile(User):
    # others fields
```

And

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # others fields
```

I don't want to know why to use one or another, but what happens under the hoods. What's the difference?

Comment: I'll say this is a duplicate of [Django: Why create a OneToOne to UserProfile instead of subclassing auth.User?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452288/django-why-create-a-onetoone-to-userprofile-instead-of-subclassing-auth-user) because the top answer there talks about the "under the hood" stuff. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221745/django-when-extending-user-better-to-use-onetoonefielduser-or-foreignkeyuse

Comment: I don't want to know why but what happens under the hoods, and @Alasdair answered it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first example is [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance).

```
class Profile(User):
```

If you have a `profile`, you can access all the fields on the user model directly (e.g. `profile.username` and `profile.email`). In this case, Django creates a `OneToOneField` for you automatically.

The second example is a regular `OneToOneField`.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

In this case, you cannot access `profile.username` and `profile.email`. Instead, you access these fields via the one to one field (e.g.  `profile.user.username` and `profile.user.email`).

In your case, where you are adding a profile model, I would avoid using inheritance, and use a one to one field instead. The `User` model has custom admins to handle passwords. If you use multi-table inheritance, then your `Profile` model would have to handle this as well. By using a one-to-one field, the custom admins can handle the user fields, and your Profile model admins only have to handle the additional profile fields.

Another option is creating a [custom user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model). In this case you subclass an abstract class `AbstractUser` or `AbstractBaseUser` instead of the class `User`. If your Profile class works, then I would recommend this instead of the custom user model, because custom user models are more complicated to set up.

Comment: I finally understood the difference! I didn't know that Django creates a `OneToOneField` when you inherits from User. I don't know what means multi-table inheritance, but I'll read the link about. Thanks!